# Identifier location has already been declared

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I am beginner at JavaScript and faced the issue saying Identifier location has already been declared but if I rename location variable into, say, locationnn then it works as expected. Here is the code I use:

```
let city ='New York';
let country = 'USA';
let location = city +","+country;

console.log(location);
```

Comment: Are you doing this interactively on the console? Perhaps you did declare `location` before…?

Comment: @deceze, thank you for your comments, is it possible that location is a keyword that was already declared globally or ?

Comment: Yes, it is a property on the global object. And trying it now, looks like that's the reason you can't redeclare it globally. I wasn't really aware of that either until now.

Comment: @mirzhal - [yes, it is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Comment: @RobinZigmond Would you mind writing this as an actual answer with some background? Would be nice, as comments are so easily overseen.

Comment: If you checked for _reserved words in javascript_ you would have found the reason for this. E.g. http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't redeclare a variable with `let` which has already been declared in the same scope. (Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Redeclarations) Note that this works fine with `var` - the declaration is simply ignored (but any assignment done alongside it still takes effect).

[location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) already exists as a global variable in the browser, and holds an object with information about the current URL. (It's most commonly referenced as `window.location`, as shown at the top of that MDN page - but `window` is the "global object" which is privileged in JS, and all its properties are the same as global variables of the same name.)

So you can't declare a global `location` variable with `let`. It *would* work with `var` instead, except not the way you think - assigning a string to the global `location` variable redirects the page (it assumes the string is a URL, if it isn't you'll just get a 404). So the short answer is that you shouldn't use `location` as a variable name, and choose something else instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you try it in browser console `location` is a global object and [contains the information about the current URL](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp). Hense when you are redeclaring it with `let location` it gives the error of 'Identifier 'location' has already been declared'

[image]